# Is there a way to change a keypress in an entry widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I press a key on an entry widget, I want that key to be uppercase. How would I do something like that? Validation just checks if you can press it, but I want the key to be changed when you press it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a `StringVar` and associating with entry widget and then calling `trace` on it:

```
var = StringVar()
e = Entry(root,textvariable=var)

var.trace('w',lambda *args: var.set(var.get().upper()))
```

**Additional:**

Can also be expanded to understand better by:

```
def caps(*args):
    text = e.get().upper() # Get the text and uppercase it
    e.delete(0,'end') # Remove all the current text
    e.insert('end',text) # Insert the upper cased text

var.trace('w',caps)
```

Also the function can be rewritten in terms of using just `var`:

```
def caps(*args):
    text = var.get().upper() # Get the text and uppercase it
    var.set('') # Remove all the current text
    var.set(text) # Insert the current text
```